# Rubyonrails mysql database connection problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a domain name and my rails application.

Is there any way to connect with database without giving the IP address of that host name?

I need what changes are needed in my database.yml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is almost certainly because you don't have a root@localhost user in your mysql database. It has nothing to do with the database configuration file.

You need to add the root@localhost user to your mysql database.

It goes without saying that you should not be using your root user in production and it is probably a good idea not to use it in dev either as it's level of privileges may be hiding some problems.

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you seeing?

If you're asking how to connect to a database without using an IP address, that depends on whether or not your database running on the same machine that's hosting your rails app?

If you're database is on the same machine as your rails app, you can just use `localhost` as your database host name and that should work (assuming your database is running with the default configurations).

Comment: the Error is " access denied for user'root' using password:yes "

Comment: if I given the host name as localhost it not working, but its a ip address its working(ie local host is as 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Sounds like you're connecting to your database just fine, you just don't have a user to log in with. You haven't specified what kind of database you're working with, but if you're not sure how to configure it you should check out the Rails Guide for getting started with rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: this is my database config file...
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: devdb
       
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1          in this case its working..  now I want to connect globle server with the help of domain name ... what changes need to  do